# How to change wiring in outdoor electrical junctions filled with gel?

Tags: electrical, junction

I moved into my current house 5 years ago and had a couple of outdoor connections fitted throughout the garden. I have never tried to do anything with them until now. As I open a junction box to add a new wiring I see this:

[image: gel filled junction box]

The box has a tiny hole, which I guess is where the gell was filled from.

I would like confirmation that I need to remove (very sticky) gel from the box, install a new connection and buy some gel to refill it. Is this the case?

Comment: Ehhhhhh...is just chopping the junction box out and replacing the entire assembly an option? Potting compounds are generally not intended to be removed.

Comment: Cut the box off and fit a new one.

Comment: This is not a potting compound it is a gel that remains soft and water protective. It is likely that you can buy it. If the new wiring doesn't require breaking into the existing wiring, consider buying a kit with a little gel-filled tube for each connection.

Comment: The gel is a silicon material. Look for materials, and instructions on YouTube etc by searching lawn irrigation system wiring or something like that.

Comment: The black deposit does not look good. May be overheated due to bad connections with high resistance. I would not trust the box and replace it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments on this. I will also follow @ThePhoton suggestions and report on Home Improvement.